# twoside breaks spacing

Tags: spacing, minipage, double-sided

I'm using minipages to keep related questions together on a test that I'm writing. When I make a 2-sided document some of my spacing gets messed up before the section break. It works fine if I leave out the twoside option. What's going on here?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article} 

\begin{document}

\section{test}
asdf

\section{More test}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
text
\vspace{7in}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"messed up" is not a very helpful description. However I assume you mean that the text comes to the bottom of the page, that is by design as `twoside` uses `\flushbottom` by default as it is traditional to ensure that the adjacent pages on a two page spread have matching bottom baselines.

However if you do not want that, add `\raggedbottom` to the preamble and you will get the same setting in the page body as for `oneside`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description. Yes, the text on page 1 gets stretched to fill up nearly the whole page, leaving inches of space between the lines. Thanks for your answer.